# Using methods inside of a method in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to access a method within another method in Vue. I'm positive I saw this done in a tutorial I followed.

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FormExample',
  methods: {
    submit() {
      validate();
      alert('done');
    },
    validate() {
      alert('validated')
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

When I trigger the `submit()` it says the validate is not defined.

I'm doing as i'd like to use the validate method in multiple methods without repeating code. Where should the validation code live if not as a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` for calling method.

```
methods: {
    submit() {
        this.validate();
        alert('done');
    },
    validate() {
        alert('validated')
    }
},
```